# Custom QGraphicsPolygonItem dragLeaveEvent not executing

Tags: c++, qt

I have a custom version of QGraphicsPolygonItem called CustomGPolygon.

In customgpolygon.h I have declared the function `void dragLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);`

The function in customgpolygon.cpp looks like this

```
void CustomGPolygon::dragLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
    event->setAccepted(true);
    qDebug() << "hi";
}
```

In the constructor of these polygons I call `setAcceptDrops(true);`.

The issue I am facing is when a polygon is moved, the "hi" isn't displayed in the console.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you have to set the flag for a CustomGPolygon's object `ItemIsMovable` ([doc](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum)):

```
void setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
```